# MongoDriver for Scala + http4s : How to check if createCollection() throws an exception?

Tags: mongodb, scala, model-view-controller, cats-effect, http4s

I'm a Scala - http4s beginner. 
I have to create a MVC application for my job using Scala with http4s and I'm facing the following problem :

### I can't catch mongo driver exceptions inside Repository

One of my tasks is to create new databases for some requests so I started to design the function "createDatabase" inside my Repository.  
According to the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.0/getting-started/quick-tour/) :

> MongoDatabase instance provides methods to interact with a database but the database might not actually exist and will only be created on the insertion of data via some means; e.g. the creation of a collection or the insertion of documents

so my code is :

```
    def createDatabase(databaseName: String) = {
        IO.fromFuture(IO {
           MongoClient("con_string").getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name").head()
        })
    }
```

expecting that a new database that contains collection with name "any_name" will be created.

*If createDatabase is called with a database name that **already exists**, the operation will fail, outputting in console* :

> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 48 (NamespaceExists): 'Collection already exists. NS: NewDbTest.customers' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Collection already exists. NS: NewDbTest.customers", "code": 48, "codeName": "NamespaceExists"}

I tried to use try {} catch, Try {}, withRecover(), and many more, hoping to catch this exception and respond with exception message, but nothing worked.

Some example:

```
    def createDatabase(databaseName: String) = {
        IO.fromFuture(IO {
            try {        
                MongoClient("con_string").getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name").head()
            }
            catch {
                case e: MongoCommandException => println("we have exception")
                Future.successful(e.getErrorMessage)
            }
        })
    }
```

```
    def createDatabase(databaseName: String) = {
        IO.fromFuture(IO {
            client.getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name").map(operation => Try {operation}).head()
        })
    }
```

```
    def createDatabase(databaseName: String) = {
        IO.fromFuture(IO {
            client.getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name").head() recover {
                case exception: Exception => Future.successful(exception.getMessage)
            }
        })
    }
```

Some snippets were obfuscated due to the confidential job agreement. 
Please help me. 
Thank you !

Comment: Is this cats IO ?

Comment: Are you sure the exception was thrown, and it was of type `MongoCommandException`? Did you try to debug and check what `MongoClient("con_string").getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name")` returns?

Comment: What is the problem in here? Lets say you have an `val io1 = IO[Int](1/0)`. This IO is supposed to fail with an `ArithamticException`. So, when you run it, you will get this exception. Your can add an `handleErrorWith` to it before running.

Comment: @sarveshseri, Yes it's cats IO

Comment: @amorfis The MongoCommandException message is right from the terminal. The MongoClient("con_string").getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name") return is shown in picture: https://ibb.co/ZVMzdGg.

Comment: @sarveshseri tied with handleErrorWith but was unable to catch it

Comment: That it shows in terminal doesn't necessary mean it is thrown from here. It might also be wrapped in something else. At the point captured in debug - was it already thrown? Maybe `head()` throws it? In debug we can clearly see that `MongoClient("con_string").getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name")` is successful and doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: `try` doesn't work with `Futures` and the latter automatically catches exceptions and `IO` also contains them. Are you familiar with following methods on `IO`: `attempt`, `recoverWith`, `on Error`? - Let me give you two advices, one you are probably trying to cover too much, you are new to the language, to the **typelevel** ecosystem and to the programs as values paradigm; take it one step at the time. - Second, I recommend you to join the **discord** servers of both **Scala** and the **typelevel** one, plenty of helpful people there.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you sir, I'm trying to solve the problem using "attempt" . Unfortunately, even if I am able to get the error message, I still can t catch it.

Comment: What do you mean with you can't catch it? Can you move the discussion to the #beginners room of the **typelevel** discord? It would be easier to help in a chat.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I ll do it in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tackled the problem using `atempt`

```sh
    def createDatabase(databaseName: String) = {
        IO.fromFuture(IO {
           MongoClient("con_string").getDatabase(databaseName).createCollection("any_name").head()
        }).attempt
    }
```

However, it seems that the error message is printed by logger at DEBUG level, no matter what happens. So I also changed the logging level to INFO.

```
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
```